# Overriding db.Model.all() in python google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, superclass, overriding

I'm trying to start using memcache in my Google App Engine app.  Instead of creating a function that checks memcache and then maybe queries the database, I decided to just override my Model's all() class method.  Here's my code so far:

```
def all(cls, order=None):
    result = memcache.get("allitems")
    if not result or not memcache.get("updateitems"):
        logging.info(list(super(Item, cls.all())))
        result = list(super(Item, cls).all()).sort(key=lambda x: getattr(x, order) if order else str(x))
        memcache.set("allitems", result)
        memcache.set("updateitems", True)
        logging.info("DB Query for items")
    return result
```

I had figured this would work.  But instead I get a RuntimeError saying that recursion depth was exceeded.  I think this comes from a misunderstanding of the super() method.  Sorry for cluttering the code up with the ordering thing.  But maybe the problem lies somewhere in there too.  One place I found said that the super method should be called like this:

```
super(supercls, cls_or_self)
```

But this wouldn't work with GAE's API:

```
super(db.Model, cls)
```

This wouldn't know which model to query.  Someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong, and maybe give me a better understanding super().

EDIT: Thanks to @Matthew, the problem turned out to be a misplaced parentheses in the first  `logging.info()` call.  Now I have another problem, the method is just returning None.  I don't know if that means that the `super` implementation of `all()` returns None (Maybe it doesn't know what entity is calling it?) or just there is some other bug with my code.

Comment: Consider also switching to NDB where you have automatic caching out of the box.. It's pretty cool: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the error might be here:

```
logging.info(list(super(Item, cls.all())))
```

If there's an error in `cls.all()`, you then call it *again* as part of the `super` constructor, rather than calling it on the result:

```
logging.info(list(super(Item, cls).all()))
```

So if an error would call `all` again it would still meet the logging branch conditions, which would call `all` again, which would still etc etc until you hit the recursion limit.

The other possible problem is that `Model.all()` returns a [`Query`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass) object, and I'm not sure if `list(query)` works. It also provides it's own sorting, so you might be able to use this instead:

```
    query = super(Item, cls).all()
    query.order( order )
    ...
return list(query)
```

Or just `return query`, as it's already iterable.

Comment: Thanks!  I commented that line out and it worked!... sort of.  Now the method returns 'None'.  Any ideas?

Comment: Does the `logging.info` line provide a list, or does it also return `None`?

Comment: It shows an empty list. The reason I know its None is because the function calling it says "Nonetype is not iterable" because I'm trying to iterate over the results of the query.  I may be wrong, but I thought you could legally "iterate" over an empty list.

Comment: It's been a good 3 years since I used GAE, so we're hitting the limits of my knowledge, unfortunately, but the problem may just be that you're expecting a list when it's returning a `Query` object. I've updated the answer.

Comment: I initialy used that approach, but then I realized (or suspected) that the query object doesnt actually read from the database until you try to iterate over it or access an element.      This of course, would defeat the purpose of caching the query. I'm still learning GAE so I might be wrong.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. Sorry, I'm sure it's possible, but I'm not familiar enough with GAE atm to be of more help. I recommend asking a new question about `Query` object caching, there may be better approaches others are already aware of.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!  Found out that I messed up by assigning the result to the return value of sort when apparently sort() sorts in place.

Comment: Ah damn, I should've caught that too, but it always bites me as well. Glad it's all working now :)